# If statement in SQL how to do it

Tags: sql, if-statement

I've got an if statement (below) which runs in Tableau. I need to turn this into SQl - I've tried lots of different case statements, but they all get errors.

Can anyone advise how I'd do this?

```
    IF LEN(REPLACE([postcode]," ","")) = 7 THEN LEFT(REPLACE([postcode]," ",""),4)+" "+RIGHT(REPLACE([postcode]," ",""),3)
ELSEIF LEN(REPLACE([postcode]," ","")) = 6 THEN LEFT(REPLACE([postcode]," ",""),3)+" "+RIGHT(REPLACE([postcode]," ",""),3)
ELSEIF LEN(REPLACE([postcode]," ","")) = 5 THEN LEFT(REPLACE([postcode]," ",""),2)+" "+RIGHT(REPLACE([postcode]," ",""),3)
END
```

Comment: Please show us what you tried so far. That could be helpful...

Comment: What were the `lots of case statements` you tried?

Comment: `case LEN(REPLACE([POSTCODE])," ", "")
 wHEN 7 THEN LEFT(REPLACE([postcode]," ",""),4)+" "+RIGHT(REPLACE([postcode]," ",""),3)
 WHEN 6 THEN LEFT(REPLACE([postcode]," ",""),3)+" "+RIGHT(REPLACE([postcode]," ",""),3)
 WHEN 5 THEN LEFT(REPLACE([postcode]," ",""),2)+" "+RIGHT(REPLACE([postcode]," ",""),3) 
END` ?

Comment: And what would ´[POSTCODE]` be? And, have you read anything regarding SQL? You won't get far with a `+` for concatenating or whatever you want to do with that. Maybe, you should clarify your question a little bit.

Comment: ANSI SQL has no LEN or ELSEIF etc... Tag the dbms you're using.

Comment: Hi, I'm actually using Hive on a Hadoop cluster - it's an SQL-Like language, which could also be reason for some of my struggles

Comment: That seems to be the problem... it`s a SQL-*LIKE* language - not SQL. So I think, you´d be better off changing the tags of your question and give the relevant details directly in the question instead of feeding us tiny piece after piece.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN LEN(REPLACE([postcode],' ','')) = 7
    THEN LEFT(REPLACE([postcode],' ',''),4)+' '+RIGHT(REPLACE([postcode],' ',''),3)
    WHEN LEN(REPLACE([postcode],' ','')) = 6
    THEN LEFT(REPLACE([postcode],' ',''),3)+' '+RIGHT(REPLACE([postcode],' ',''),3)
    WHEN LEN(REPLACE([postcode],' ','')) = 5
    THEN LEFT(REPLACE([postcode],' ',''),2)+' '+RIGHT(REPLACE([postcode],' ',''),3)
    ELSE 'ERROR'
  END
FROM YOUR_TABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just replace the `IF` in your statement by `CASE WHEN`
And all the `ELSEIF` by `WHEN`

But you can probably also simplify it to :

```
CASE 
WHEN LEN(REPLACE([POSTCODE]," ","")) IN (5,6,7) THEN REPLACE ([POSTCODE]," ","")
ELSE NULL
END
```

Since f.e. "ABC" + "DEF" = "ABCDEF" = "ABC   DEF" without spaces.

Comment: This is awesome. Sadly, I get this error:  Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 4:17 cannot recognize input near '[' 'POSTCODE' ']' in function specification --- can you advise?

Comment: Uhm, try it with double quotes instead of single quotes?  I originally thought this was for T-SQL, which uses single quotes for text.

Answer (score 0):

As the OP stated after some querying, he is using Hive on Hadoop - not plain SQL.

So - maybe - this could get you started: https://de.hortonworks.com/blog/hive-cheat-sheet-for-sql-users/